# Obtener dos datos de una tabla creando col con su informacion (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql

Quiero hacer una consulta que tenga dos cols con la informacion del empleado.
No sé como hacerlo, 
Mi codigo:

```
select * from empleados 
inner join historia 
on empleados.id_em=historia.id_em;
```

Tablas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te comparto la respuesta de este modo:

```
SELECT empleados.id, 
       empleados.nombre,
       SUM(CASE WHEN historias.tipo = 1 THEN historias.pago ELSE NULL END) AS Col1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN historias.tipo = 2 THEN historias.pago ELSE NULL END) AS Col2
FROM empleados
JOIN historias ON empleados.id = historias.id_emp
GROUP BY empleados.id, empleados.nombre;
```

**Explicación**

- Hacemos por cada columna que deseamos mostrar el tipo un condicional con el uso de `CASE` identificando si la tabla `historia` es igual a 1 o 2.
- Agrupamos por el `id` y el `nombre` del empleado.
- Hacemos uso de la función de agregación `SUM()` que reduce a un renglón por cada vez que itera y encuentra coincidencias establecidas por el `CASE` para que de este modo solo aparezca un valor 100 o 90 a cada uno de los empleados.
- Para este caso en concreto la función de agregación `SUM` no altera las cifras de los pagos, por que solo existe uno de estos por cada usuario y tipo de historia

**Resultado**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Referencias**

- [Enlace al ejemplo funcional](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=73d53673aee5d5e6e9995bc72ca00743)
- [Acerca de `CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html)

Comment: como podría incluir un inner join dentro del **case**?  `SUM(CASE WHEN historias.tipo = 2 THEN historias.pago ELSE NULL END) AS Col2`

Comment: hola @Carlos me parece que para mantener la integridad de esta pregunta y respuestas, deberías abrir una nueva pregunta, bajo las reglas de [ask], indicando el problema y lo que llevas al momento, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Solo tengo a la mano SqlServer, deberás traducirla

```
select 
    nombre,
    tipo_1 = sum(iif(tipo=1,pago,0)),
    tipo_2 = sum(iif(tipo=2,pago,0))
from #empleados e
inner join #historia h on h.idEmpleado = e.idEmpleado
group by nombre;
```

**Ejecución en SqlServer.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Como se explica este codigo:  `sum(iif(tipo=1,pago,0))` solo esto no entiendo

Comment: Si tipo  = 1 suma pago de lo contrario suma 0